# For vectors $a$ and $b$ we have $|a|=\sqrt{2} |b|$ what is the angle between $a+b$ and $a-b$

Tags: geometry, vectors

By using the cosine formula:
 $$\cos(\theta)= \frac{(a+b)(a-b)}{|a+b||a-b|}$$
By working this out I always end up with the nominator and denominator canceling out without me even having to use the magnitude relations, i.e 
$$\frac{(|a|^2-|b|^2)}{\sqrt{(|a|^2-|b|^2)^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks to Paul for the edit. I am not used to coding it nicely. I realized there is no real question in my question. I guess it is what am I doing wrong ? Could someone show me how to work through it and possibly where my mistake is? Thanks !

Comment: Don't you know the angle between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Are you sure that the last formula is equivalent to the first one?

Comment: No information is given about the angle between a and b and I believe that I am doing something wrong when transforming the formula hence why I am getting that the the angle between a+b and a-b for any 2 vectors a and b will be 0.

Comment: There is clearly not enough information. Working in the plane, suppose that $b=\langle 1,0\rangle$ and $a=\langle\sqrt2,0\rangle$; then the angle between $a+b=\langle\sqrt2+1,0\rangle$ and $a-b=\langle\sqrt2-1,0\rangle$ is $0$. But if $b=\langle 1,0\rangle$ and $a=\langle 0,\sqrt2\rangle$, the angle between $a+b=\langle 1,\sqrt2\rangle$ and $a-b=\langle-1,\sqrt2\rangle$ is clearly not $0$, and both of these cases are consistent with the available information.